# How to perform multilevel lookup with possible missing values at the each level?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dictionary, default-value

I'm creating several variables based on query string parameters, and I have two options:

1. Single-line if/else statement

   ```
   foo = event['queryStringParameters']['foo'] if event['queryStringParameters'] and 'foo' in event['queryStringParameters'] else None
   ```
2. Four-line try/except statement

   ```
   try:
       foo = event['queryStringParameters']['foo']
   except (KeyError, TypeError):
       foo = None
   ```

Note: the event is from AWS Lambda, so I don't have control over it

Comment: Do you control `event`? Can you make it into a defaultdict?

Comment: The first snippet is so wide, I have to scroll it by over 4 screen widths.

Comment: What is the source of this dict, a JSON or similar? Maybe we can leverage this.

Comment: @Alexander but why?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why what?

Comment: @Alexander why would you *want* it to be a `defaultdict`? Often, you don't *want* those semantics. If the only reason is to avoid doing one of the two above, then probably, IMO, it isn't what you want

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Often you don't, but here it would be useful.

Comment: @Alexander I don't think it would. I think the second form here is pythonic.

Comment: @Alexander The event is from AWS Lambda

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you would just make `event` into a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (configured so that intermediate dicts return `{}` and leaf dicts return `None`).

You can emulate that yourself at the callsite, by using [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead of `[]`:

```
foo = event.get('queryStringParameters', {}).get('foo', None)
```

But as you see, it's more cumbersome.

Comment: how would you configure a defaultdict to distinguish between "intermediate" and "leaf" nodes, unless you now the expected depth beforehand? This could use an actual concrete example

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good question. You're right, you would need to know the depth beforehand. That may or may not be possible, depending on OPs circumstances, which we don't know about. Without further details, a concrete example would just be a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 3):

The second version with the try/except is more easily digestible.

If you have an aversion to try/except, the [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method would also be useful here:

```
qsp = event.get('queryStringParameters')
foo = qsp and asp.get('foo')
```

As suggested by the commenter, a match/case (for Python 3.10 or later) would also work, but I don't think it is as clear as the try/except version or the get() version:

```
match event:
    case {'queryStringParameters': {'foo': foo}}: pass
    case _: foo = None
```

Comment: Btw, would you recommend `match` syntax for these kinds of problems? Something like `case {'queryStringParameters': {'foo': val, **x}, **y}`?

Comment: Yes, that would work as well.   I don't think it is a win for clarity though.

Comment: I'm stuck in Python 3.7, so `match` isn't an option

Comment: @acoordes the `try-except` approach you have is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

Let's try generalizing the kind of logic @Alexander employed in that answer to allow for looking up with any number of levels of nested dictionaries.

```
def nested_get(d, default_val, *keys):
    d2 = d
    for k in keys:
        if not isinstance(d2, dict): return default_val
        d2 = d2.get(k, {})
    return d2
```

Now:

```
foo = nested_get(event, None, 'queryStringParameters', 'foo')
```